# Помогите с регуляркой для MySQL

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

В БД MySQL, в поле типа varchar, в строке хранится либо 1 IP адрес, либо несколько через запятую.

```
123.22.33.12,21.24.54.215,234.23.15.35
```

Необходимо осуществлять поиск по этой строке заданного IP-адреса.
Через LIKE %IP_ADRESS% не получится, т.к. например запрос IP "21.24.54.2" будет совпадать со строкой выше. Но ведь там другой IP 21.24.54.215.
Остаётся использовать REGEXP, благо строк в таблице меньше сотни, тормозить не будет.
Помогите с регуляркой, думал использовать что-то вроде `\D123.22.33.12\D` , но возникают проблемы с началом и концом строки. В регулярках не силён, поэтому прошу помощи.

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(@ip_address, table.ip_addresses)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
WHERE `ip` REGEXP '(^|\D)".$server_ip."(,|$)'
```

Переменную $server_ip необходимо дополнительно обработать методом real_escape_string -   [real-escape-string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)